# groupjoin couldn't work

Tags: linq, join

I have code like this

```
var db = new BigDataEntities(); 
var g = db.Tab1
           .GroupJoin(db.Tab1, a => a.id, b => b.id, (a, b) => new {a, b})
           .GroupJoin(db.Tab1, c => c.a.id, d => d.id, (c, d) => new {c, d})
           .Select(t => t.c.b.id);
```

I'm not sure why I use t.c.a.id works well, but t.c.b.id can't work, I can't get 'id' from t.c.b; If I use Join instead of GroupJoin, everything works well. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `t.c.b` is an `IEnumerable<b>`. When you use `Join`, `new {a, b}` is an IEnumerable of an anonymous type having properties `a` and `b`.